# Application crash if GPS get disable in background in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, location

I am using below code to check if GPS is enable or not if not then please ask permission and once it is enable user can navigate to next screen(next screen just have one label in it.No other functionality is there in next screen).
It works properly.

Problem is : It crash my application if i perform below action -
1) Allow the location permission i.e GPS is enable
2) User navigate to next screen
3) App moves background .Then app move to foreground everthing works fine.
But if app move background and i disable the GPS from settings - it crash the app in background itself.

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


 bool isLocationEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();
        GeolocationStatus _permission;

        if (isLocationEnabled) {
          print("enable");
          _permission = await Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();
          print("Permission result: $_permission");
          if (_permission == GeolocationStatus.granted) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HOME_SCREEN);
          }else{
            print("permission not enable");
          }
        } else {
          print("not enable");
        }
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Any solution on this yet?

Comment: No solution yet.

Comment: Looks like it's normal app behavior in Android. https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/406

Answer (score 1):

The real cause behind this is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted" you can check out this thread on github :

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29092

you can add try catch around the line causing problem in the java class and print some message instead of crashing the app until a solution is found.